# PhpSpreadsheet - How to make part of the text bold

Tags: phpspreadsheet

How do I bold several words I want in a cell?

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\{Font, Border, Alignment};
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText;
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
....
```

Answer (score 3):

```php
$richText = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\RichText\RichText();
$richText->createText('This invoice is ');
$payable = $richText->createTextRun('payable within thirty days after the end of the month');
$payable->getFont()->setBold(true);
$payable->getFont()->setItalic(true);
$payable->getFont()->setColor( new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color::COLOR_DARKGREEN ) );
$richText->createText(', unless specified otherwise on the invoice.');
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A18')->setValue($richText);
```

from: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-rich-text-to-a-cell